# Performance issues when parsing big file with awk

Tags: performance, awk

I would like to parse a mail.log file to get the last occurrences of a two patterns in the same line, files to be parsed have a size between 500MB & 1 GB

I managed to get it with :

```
$ time awk ' $5~"postfix/error" && $6~"4F0A73A11CF"  ' MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log | 
tail -1

Feb 26 21:49:23 smtp1 postfix/error[32347]: 4F0A73A11CF: to=<xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.xx>, 
relay=none, delay=88661, delays=88661/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery 
temporarily suspended: connect to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[x.x.x.x]:25: Connection timed out)

real    0m3.572s
user    0m1.920s
sys     0m1.600s
```

I would like to keep using the awk command, but I drastically need to improve the performance for parsing several days of data.

By using the tac command to reverse the file, starting with the last one, I observed improved performance with the grep command:

```
$ time tac MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log | grep "postfix/error" | grep -m1 "4F0A73A11CF"

Feb 26 21:49:23 smtp1 postfix/error[32347]: 4F0A73A11CF: to=<xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.xx>, 
relay=none, delay=88661, delays=88661/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery 
temporarily suspended: connect to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[x.x.x.x]:25: Connection timed out)

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.016s

$ time cat MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log | grep "postfix/error" | grep "4F0A73A11CF"  | 
tail -1

Feb 26 21:49:23 smtp1 postfix/error[32347]: 4F0A73A11CF: to=<xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.xx>, 
relay=none, delay=88661, delays=88661/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery 
temporarily suspended: connect to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[x.x.x.x]:25: Connection timed out)

real    0m2.979s
user    0m0.280s
sys     0m0.680s
```

But when trying to combine the tac and the awk command, the performance are not the one expected:

```
time tac MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log | awk ' $5~"postfix/error" && $6~"4F0A73A11CF" ' | 
head -1

Feb 26 21:49:23 smtp1 postfix/error[32347]: 4F0A73A11CF: to=<xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.xx>, 
relay=none, delay=88661, delays=88661/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery 
temporarily suspended: connect to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[x.x.x.x]:25: Connection timed out)

real    0m19.232s
user    0m2.840s
sys     0m4.836s
```

Any suggestions

Regards

Comment: Making assumptions from looking at your one line of data, maybe if you include `[` and `:` as field separators, you could use `=` instead of `~` in your awk condition (note that the field numbers would change as well).

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment about the "[", I tried :
    time tac MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log | awk -F':' ' $3~"postfix/error" && $4==" 4F0A73A11CF" ' |  head -1

    real    0m16.003s
    user    0m2.756s
    sys     0m3.984s

I had to add a space for the 4th field the " 4F0A73A11CF", no big improvement.

Comment: Is is possible to stop the awk command after the first match like "grep -m1"
otherwise using tac is useless

Comment: Yes, you can use `exit`:   https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html

Comment: @user3489729, jas's first statement is correct. Try a string comparison instead of a regexp comparison: `awk -F'[][: ]+' '$7=="postfix/error" && $9=="4F0A73A11CF"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is piping to head, when exiting after the first match, performance are increased:

```
time tac MAIL-POSTFIX-LOG-20160226.log |  awk ' $5~"error" && $6~"4F0A73A11CF" {print; exit} '

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Comment: right. you're now removing any buffering issues in the pipeline and definitely stopping awk at the first match. Also, note that by using string delimiters (`"..."`) around your regexps instead of regexp delimiters (`/.../`) you are forcing awk to work twice as hard, once to convert the strings to regexps and then again to evaluate the regexp. Use regexp delimiters to delimit regexps: `$5~/error/ && $6~/4F0A73A11CF/`. You might also find a small improvement with one regexp comparison instead of 2: `awk '/postfix\/error\[[0-9]+\]: 4F0A73A11CF/{print; exit}'`.

Comment: Thx to all, I was not aware of the possibility to use multiple delimiter with awk, neither on the impact of using  string delimiters with regexps.